# Draw curve -> Get equation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, computer-science

A part of the project I am working on requires an interface where a user draws a curve, and I want to output an approximate mathematical equation of that curve to perform a variety of tests on it.

I have thought of 2 approaches so far and was wondering if they are feasible or if there exists a better way of approaching the problem that I am missing/ cool mathematical trick that allows me to pull this off.

**Approach 1:**

Instead of having users draw a curve, give them the option of inserting bezier curve points and tweaking them to make their curve. Since bezier curves have a parametric equation that describes them, I could directly get the exact equation.

Cons:
-It's more cumbersome for users to tweak and make a bezier than simply draw a curve

**Approach 2:**

Get the curve drawn and extract 'n' points. (I don't think this should be hard to do).
Somehow go from these 'n' points to an equation of a curve passing through them. Naturally 'n' would be pretty large, say 100.
Is there a neat way to get an equation for the "simplest continuous function" passing through 'n' points?

Comment: To obtain the formula from a graph it might be a good idea to look into linear or polynomial regression algorithms. [A good read about regression algorithms in JS](https://medium.com/guidesmiths-dev/building-a-polynomial-regression-model-factory-in-nodejs-bb0643be258)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 -- insert Bezier points and tweak control points -- is used in a lot of vector drawing programs, especially CAD-type applications where precision is important and points are laid out on a grid, etc.  It is a slower way to draw, but it's used in these situations, because it's really difficult to draw a freehand curve *carefully*.

Approach 2 -- just draw and get an smooth approximation -- is also pretty popular when precision isn't required.  I'm not sure what methods are usually used for this, or even if there is a "usually", but I don't think it's particularly difficult to do a pretty good job.  I would:

1. Connect all the points with line segments in the order in which they were drawn.
2. Apply the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm to reduce the number of points.
3. Interpolate the points with [cubic spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).  Be careful looking this up-there are many flavors of cubic spline interpolation and their names overlap.  I would specifically prefer the versions that preserve 2nd derivative continuity.